# What is the use of 'duplicate' functions in the GAE api?

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7

While working on a GAE project in python I noticed that my IDE (eclipse) suggested a couple of methods that appeared to be the same:

[image: mail]

I'm going to be using this api to send emails and [according to the docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/#Python_Sending_mail_in_Python) the `send_mail` should be used for this. However when I saw the `SendMail` in eclipse I started to wonder if maybe one of them is deprecated, so I went and searched for information about that.

I came across [the page that documents the functions that the mail api offers](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/functions) and noticed that `SendMail` is not included there, which I found strange.

Next thing I did was check the [source code for the mail api](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/functions) for anything that could tell me more about this, and there (line 376) I found:

```
def send_mail(sender,
          to,
          subject,
          body,
          make_sync_call=apiproxy_stub_map.MakeSyncCall,
          **kw):
  """Sends mail on behalf of application.

  Args:
    sender: Sender email address as appears in the 'from' email line.
    to: List of 'to' addresses or a single address.
    subject: Message subject string.
    body: Body of type text/plain.
    make_sync_call: Function used to make sync call to API proxy.
    kw: Keyword arguments compatible with EmailMessage keyword based
      constructor.

  Raises:
    InvalidEmailError when invalid email address provided.
  """
  kw['sender'] = sender
  kw['to'] = to
  kw['subject'] = subject
  kw['body'] = body
  message = EmailMessage(**kw)
  message.send(make_sync_call)


SendMail = send_mail
```

What caught my attention is the bottom line

```
SendMail = send_mail
```

---

Conclusion: they are the same. What could be the reason for offering the same function twice through different names?

I googled around for a bit trying to find a reason why you would want to do this but I couldn't find anything. Even though I'm clearly no expert, it doesn't seem to add any value.

Comment: it's a good question - i've seen this a lot in google apis. i presumed it was just to offer the 2 coding styles, but would be interested to know if there was another reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect this is just a case of Google's internal style being different from their public one. Internally, the Python style guide enforces CamelCase for all functions and methods as well as classes (no idea why). Externally, they follow the PEP8 recommendation for functions being lower_case_with_underscore. This sort of aliasing just translates from one style to the other.

Comment: Can you show me where you found that information? I figured I could read about it here http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/pyguide.html#Naming but that says to use snake case for function names.

Comment: I found it by means of previously working at Google and having what is referred to as "Python readability", which means I was trusted to write Python according to the internal style guide. (I didn't work on any of this code though, so I'm only assuming that's the reason for the duplication.)

Comment: Despite the fact that I'm unable to find any documentation on this, I don't think I'll get a better answer than one from a previous employee of google who worked with python, so I'll accept it :-)